# Unrecognized character in filename (linux)

Tags: linux, filenames, character-encoding, special-characters

I have a problem accessing file in linux Mint. The reason is obviously the unrecognized character(s) in the filename but none of the techniques I know helped me to rename it.

So, here are details:
filename is something like:

```
êà_0_4àíòè_0_7-_0_7_0_8ó_0_1à333333.mp3
```

or at least this is how my filemanager and terminal display it.

I cannot open the file with any program I use under linux Mint. media players, etc...

It cannot be renamed, moved or copied via file manager. All of these operations produce error messages similar to these:

(for rename):

```
Error renaming file: No such file or directory.
```

(for copy/move):

```
No such file or directory.
```

I have also tried rename command from terminal using wildcards. The command correctly picks the file name but cannot copy, here is the output:

```
cp *0_7-_* 1.mp3
cp: cannot open `êà_0_4àíòè_0_7-_0_7_0_8ó_0_1à333333.mp3' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried using mv command,

```
mv *0_7-_* 1.mp3
mv: cannot move `êà_0_4àíòè_0_7-_0_7_0_8ó_0_1à333333.mp3' to `1.mp3': No such file or directory
```

If I try to **sudo rename** then I get:

```
Unrecognized character \xC3; marked by <-- HERE after <-- HERE near column 1 at (eval 1) line 1.
```

File itself is a valid MP3 file. It can be opened by Windows Media Player under XP.

The problem is: I have a big music library (over 100Gb) and there are few dosens of similar files with invalid characters in names. I don't want to loose these files and I would like to figure out how to handle such situations in future (in linux preferably, because I don't own a pc that runs windows).

Any help will be appreciated

**UPDATE:**
as requested by terdon, here is the outout of `locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**UPDATE 2**
I have just checked with my friends XP machine. And I can confirm following findings.
The original file can be played by Windows Media Player but it cannot be played by Winamp.
However after accessing and renaming it through filemanager it is played by both players.

So I conclude that this **is** a problem with unrecognized character. I am still interested in solution under linux though,

Comment: Could you show us the output of `locale` please? I'm guessing you are not using UTF8.

Comment: please see above. I have updated the question adding the output of `locale`

Comment: Hmm, that is weird. I tried simply creating a file with the same name and it worked fine. What filesystem are these on?

Comment: its NTFS. not sure if creating file with this name proves anything. I have just tried it myself and I can do it too, I can also modify, open, rename and delete the file after I have created it. I assume that what I have pasted in my original question is not the actual filename but the way my systems sees/interprets it.

Comment: @smc Is the filesystem clean? `chkdsk x:` in an elevated command line does an read-only check, so nothing will be altered. (Sorry, your on linux... this should be then `ntfsfix -n /dev/sdX`, `-n` for dry run).

Comment: I quite agree that it proves nothing but it was the best I could do :). Do you think you could provide us with an example file so we could play around with it? Also try `find . -name "*0_7-_*" -exec mv {} 1.mp3 \;` and let us know if that fares any better. Oh, and show us the output of `file "*0_7-_*"` as well please. You might also want to try and move the parent folder to a different filesystem and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: answering your first question. yes the system is clean. I used `fsck`  to check.

Comment: I am trying to think about how to provide you with example files, but I cannot come up with a reasonable way of doing it. File cannot be read on my machine - thus it cannot be uploaded. Any hints? BTW, I appreciate your wish to help

Comment: output of commands that you have suggested. both result in "no such file or directory" however I can see that it displays the full file name (So I am sure I used the wildcards * right way)

Answer (score 2):

Four things:

**Try the complement of the solution - move everything else, then remove everything.**

```
mkdir ../everything_else
mv problematic/folder/path/* everything_else
sudo rm -rf problematic/folder/path
```

**Make sure there is no ACL on the file, and remove any that may be causing problems:**

```
$ /bin/ls -le problematic/folder/path
total 16
-rw-r--r--+ 1 whmcclos  staff  1918 Dec 18 09:00 README
0: user:_spotlight inherited allow read,execute,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity
$ chmod -a "..."
```

**Try a Perl script to smooth out OS/FS naming dependencies?**

For instance, something along the lines of this code fragment - keep the filename in anonymous $_:

```
$ mkdir fred; cd fred; touch a b c d e f
$ cat > try.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
opendir(D,".") or die "cannot open .\n";
@files=readdir(D);
closedir(D);
foreach (@files) {
  next if /\.{1,2}/;                      # Skip directory entries
  print; print "? "; $r = <>; chop($r);   # Provide some level of control
  if($r eq "y" or $r eq "Y") {unlink;}    # Should report if cannot unlink unnamed file - tbd.
}
^D
$ /usr/bin/perl try.pl
a? 
b? 
c? y
d? 
e? 
f? 
$ ls
a       b       d       e       f       try.pl
```

[Updated to reflect authors original intent - copy the beast to a well behaved file(name):]

To see if Perl can copy the misbehaved file to a well behaved file, I'd use the below Perl script - still along the lines of the above - let Perl "anonymously" access the filename.

(Also, the ACL should really be checked; the ACL can even prevent root from normally accessing the file as root, from what I recall dealing with.]

Here's the Perl script:

```
$ cat try3.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
# A code fragment to ask to copy a displayed file to $TO; chg $TO on next line:
$TO="my_new_behaved_filename";       # This is the name that will be copied to
opendir(D,".") or die "cannot open .\n";
@files=readdir(D);
closedir(D);
foreach $f (@files) {
  next if $f =~ /\.{1,2}/;           # Skip directory entries, "." & ".."
  print "$f? "; $r = <>; chop($r);   # Provide some level of control; "y" or "Y"
  if($r eq "y" or $r eq "Y") {       #   to copy the displayed filename to $TO
    print "copying it to $TO...\n";
    # Now, see if we can copy the darn thing to $TO:
    open(FROM,$f) or die "sorry - couldn't open it...";
    open(TO,">$TO");
    while(read FROM, $buf, 16384) {
      print TO $buf;
    }
    close(TO);
    close(FROM);
  }
}
```

Which you'd use as such, assuming try3.pl is the aforementioned Perl script:

```
$ ./try3.pl 
a? 
b? 
d? y
copying it to my_new_behaved_filename...
e? 
f?
```

**Access the file through a symbolic or hard link and see what milage you get.**

I'd use vi's filename [tab] expansion to try to "identify" to the shell what file you want to link to.

I moved my ~/{.vim,.viminfo,.vimrc} aside so as to restrict things, like wildmenu input.  You may want to do the same.

Now, kick off the following command line sequence in the bogus file's containing folder:

```
$ vi
```

In vi, type precisely this sequence of characters

```
!!ln -s [tab]
```

So that key sequence was, in words: exclamation point, exclamation point, el, en, blank, dash, es, blank, tab.  As soon as you hit the [tab] key, the first file of the current working directory *should* display after the blank character (following the "s") on vi's status line.  Hit the [tab] key numerous times to cycle through to the bogus filename.  When the bogus filename appears, press the space bar to add a space, and then type a new file/link-name.

The result on vi's status line should look something like this

```
!!ln -s bogus_filename new_sym_link_name
```

Hit the return key to see if the link command (spawned from vi to replace the current null line in vi's empty buffer, which we don't care about, here; we want the side effect of executing a shell command with tab expansion) will create the link, new_sym_link_name.

Exit vi with :q![return], and see if you can access your file through the symbolic link.

(You could also try a hard link by leaving off the -s in the above ln command.

*Because I just noticed that you could change the filename through Windows, I'm thinking that somehow, a carriage-return linefeed sequence got into the filename, and that is confusing the various approaches.*

Comment: This comment is on your perl script. I tried it but it did not work. Thanks for help though. I was hoping that something like this should solve my problem.. What happened was, I created the script in the directory with affected files. I ran the script. I tried it first by removing the files that I have created for testing (a,b,c,d,e and f). worked fine. then I tried removing other random files in the directory. worked as well. But when trying to remove files affected by the problem nothing happened. Files were not removed and no error was reported. I will try other two methods that you suggest

Comment: moving then removing everything did not work either. moving was successful, removing reported error (no such file or directory). I think it is important to note here that I am not trying to remove files. As noted in my original question I am trying to access files and I cannot because the invalid filename. So I am looking for a way to rename the file to be able to access it. (thanks for your help). I only mentioned that i am unable to remove files in order to give as much details as possible, still my actual task is to rename.

Comment: I have installed radiance package in order to run total as you advised. I ran the command : `total 01\ _0_1cie_0_4ka\ 1.mp3` and the result was `01 _0_1cie_0_4ka 1.mp3: cannot open`

Comment: Bill, thanks a lot. I see you know much more then I do on the subject.  And about ACL... I guess this is not the case. all affected files state rwxrwxrwx. Once again I will repeat, I am pretty sure that this is the case of having an invalid character in the name. I guess you have already read my update on original question: renaming file from windows pc makes it accessible on **any** system. I still cannot find a way to rename it from linux. I will try the second version of the script tomorrow first thing.

Comment: Couldn't resist and tried it right now. script works for all other files (which means it is correct and compiles perfectly). But when I try to use it to rename affected files it dies with ""sorry - couldn't open it...""

Comment: The trick with vim does not work either. Creating symbolic link is ok, but accessing file through that link results into error (no such file or directory). Creating hard link does not work (shell returned 1)

Comment: Executing `ln` on a hard link will fail if `ln` cannot find one of its args ("No such file or directory"), if the args are on different FS ("Cross-device link") or if the link is to a directory ("Is a directory"), all three return `$?` set to `1`.  Did the hard link case return any of the above parenthesized strings i.e. "ln: fred: Cross-device link" and what you noticed, `$? = 1`.  It would be illuminating if the message was other than, "No such file or directory."

Comment: Bill, once again, thanks for your patience and help. I guess I was not specific enough. So. I am not familiar with vim, but when I try to execute "!!ln <affected_file> <new_name>", what I get is a string that literally says "shell returned 1" and then "press ENTER or type command co continue". No link is being created at this point. I have also double checked to make sure that I can link other files within directory (not affected ones) and this works ok.

Comment: You were able to rename on Windows, but not on linux? "renaming file from windows pc makes it accessible on any system. I still cannot find a way to rename it from linux" Is this a portable NTFS drive that you plugin to a Linux box, or a mounted NTFS exported from aWindows to linux? I'd like to visualize the mechanics of how the file is mounted.

Comment: It is portable NTFS. USB hdd to be precise.

Comment: Have you tried network mounting the drive from a Windows host, either from a real Windows one or from a VM?  Try to see if you can access the mounted FS (and change the file) from an exported FS; one from a true Windows NTFS driver a la the Windows machine over a network to see if the problem lies with the linux `mount -t ntfs` command or one of its variants.  From what I recall, NTFS was difficult to port, if not impossible - not sure how far that effort matured.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ls -li` to get the inode number of the file in question. Make a note of of the inode number (first field). I'll use `123456` as an example.

Then, use `find` to remove the file:

```
find -inum 123456 -exec rm {} \;
```

or to rename it:

```
find -inum 123456 -exec mv {} some_better_filename \;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. here is what happens:
`ls -li` will list the files (and display inodes). In my case the inode number was 28623.
then running
`find -inum 28623 -exec mv {} some_better_filename.mp3 \;`
results in
`mv: cannot move "./01 _0_1cie_0_4ka 1.mp3" to "some_better_filename.mp3": No such file or directory`
as you can see, using inode number to identify file - works, but accessing it doesn't.

Comment: I think the culprit is that `find` passes filename to `mv` and the filename is problematic. Don't know how to fix it, though.

Comment: I completely agree with gronostaj. It is the filename that is problematic. Also see update 2 at the bottom of original question. Still no solution though. I appreciate any suggestions